# Can I take prescribed antimalaria tablets to Dubai?

Tags: luggage, health, dubai, uae, drugs

yesterday I got antimalarial tablets *Atovaquon proguanil* at the travel clinic he told me I wouldn't need a prescription for this the thing is my flight is in Dubai will it be okay if I can put them in my hand luggage? I'm getting paranoid.

Comment: Hand luggage or checked luggage does not matter; you will pick up the checked baggage before you pass through customs anyway. (I don't know what the UAE thinks about this medication, though).

Comment: From skimming a bunch of expat forums, it seems that Malarone is no longer available in Dubai but nobody has ever had a problem importing it that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

A list of controlled and semi-controlled medicines, allowed quantities and documents to present for approval, if needed, can be found on the [UAE Ministry of Health website](http://www.mohap.gov.ae/) (see: [Travellers Guideline.pdf](http://www.mohap.gov.ae/Files/MOH_Service/361/Travellers%20Guideline.pdf) and [ANNEX-TO-TRAVELLERS-GUIDELINES-1.pdf](https://loyaltylobby.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/ANNEX-TO-TRAVELLERS-GUIDELINES-1.pdf)). As far as I can see, the medication you mention isn’t included.

If you want to play safe and get confirmation before you travel, you can contact the UAE Ministry of Health directly by emailing `info@moh.gov.ae`. I did this last November and received a reply within a couple of days, which I carried with me on my trip.